How to make horizontal data vertical?
Here, I scraped the English Premier League table from 2021/22 to 2024 season using Selenium and stored it in table_data which looks like this:
[['1',
  'Arsenal',
  '33 23 5 5 77 26 51 74',
  'D',
  'W',
  'W',
  'L',
  'W',
  '2',
  'Liverpool',
  '33 22 8 3 75 32 43 74',
  'W',
  'W',
  'D',
  'L',
  'W',
  '3',
  'Manchester City',
  '32 22 7 3 76 32 44 73',
  'D',
  'D',
  'W',
  'W',
  'W',
  '4',
  'Aston Villa',
  '34 20 6 8 71 50 21 66',
  'W',
  'L',
  'D',
  'W',
  'W',
  '5',
  'Tottenham Hotspur',
  '32 18 6 8 65 49 16 60',
  'L',
  'W',
  'D',
  'W',
  'L',
  '6',
  'Newcastle United',
  '32 15 5 12 69 52 17 50',
  'L',
  'W',
  'D',
  'W',
  'W',
  '7',
  'Manchester United',
  '32 15 5 12 47 48 -1 50',
  'W',
  'D',
  'L',
  'D',
  'D',
  '8',
  'West Ham United',
  '34 13 9 12 54 63 -9 48',
  'L',
  'D',
  'W',
  'L',
  'L',
  '9',
  'Chelsea',
  '31 13 8 10 61 52 9 47',
  'W',
  'D',
  'W',
  'D',
  'W',
  '10',
  'Brighton And Hove Albion',
  '32 11 11 10 52 50 2 44',
  'W',
  'L',
  'D',
  'L',
  'D',
  '11',
  'Wolverhampton Wanderers',
  '33 12 7 14 46 53 -7 43',
  'L',
  'D',
  'L',
  'D',
  'L',
  '12',
  'Fulham',
  '34 12 6 16 50 54 -4 42',
  'D',
  'L',
  'L',
  'W',
  'L',
  '13',
  'Bournemouth',
  '33 11 9 13 48 60 -12 42',
  'W',
  'W',
  'L',
  'D',
  'L',
  '14',
  'Crystal Palace',
  '33 9 9 15 42 56 -14 36',
  'D',
  'L',
  'L',
  'W',
  'W',
  '15',
  'Brentford',
  '34 9 8 17 52 59 -7 35',
  'D',
  'D',
  'D',
  'W',
  'W',
  '16',
  'Everton',
  '33 10 8 15 34 48 -14 30',
  'L',
  'D',
  'W',
  'L',
  'W',
  '17',
  'Nottingham Forest',
  '34 7 9 18 42 60 -18 26',
  'D',
  'W',
  'L',
  'D',
  'L',
  '18',
  'Luton Town',
  '34 6 7 21 47 75 -28 25',
  'L',
  'L',
  'W',
  'L',
  'L',
  '19',
  'Burnley',
  '34 5 8 21 37 69 -32 23',
  'D',
  'D',
  'L',
  'D',
  'W',
  '20',
  'Sheffield United',
  '33 3 7 23 31 88 -57 16',
  'D',
  'L',
  'D',
  'L',
  'L'],
 ['1',
  'Manchester City',
  '38 28 5 5 94 33 61 89',
  'W',
  'W',
  'W',
  'D',
  'L',
  '2',
  'Arsenal',
  '38 26 6 6 88 43 45 84',
  'W',
  'W',
  'L',
  'L',
  'W',
  '3',
  'Manchester United',
  '38 23 6 9 58 43 15 75',
  'L',
  'W',
  'W',
  'W',
  'W',
  '4',
  'Newcastle United',
  '38 19 14 5 68 33 35 71',
  'L',
  'D',
  'W',
  'D',
  'D',
  '5',
  'Liverpool',
  '38 19 10 9 75 47 28 67',
  'W',
  'W',
  'W',
  'D',
  'D',
  '6',
  'Brighton And Hove Albion',
  '38 18 8 12 72 53 19 62',
  'W',
  'L',
  'W',
  'D',
  'L',
  '7',
  'Aston Villa',
  '38 18 7 13 51 46 5 61',
  'L',
  'L',
  'W',
  'D',
  'W',
  '8',
  'Tottenham Hotspur',
  '38 18 6 14 70 63 7 60',
  'L',
  'W',
  'L',
  'L',
  'W',
  '9',
  'Brentford',
  '38 15 14 9 58 46 12 59',
  'W',
  'L',
  'W',
  'W',
  'W',
  '10',
  'Fulham',
  '38 15 7 16 55 53 2 52',
  'L',
  'W',
  'W',
  'D',
  'L',
  '11',
  'Crystal Palace',
  '38 11 12 15 40 49 -9 45',
  'W',
  'L',
  'W',
  'D',
  'D',
  '12',
  'Chelsea',
  '38 11 11 16 38 47 -9 44',
  'W',
  'D',
  'L',
  'L',
  'D',
  '13',
  'Wolverhampton Wanderers',
  '38 11 8 19 31 58 -27 41',
  'L',
  'W',
  'L',
  'D',
  'L',
  '14',
  'West Ham United',
  '38 11 7 20 42 55 -13 40',
  'L',
  'W',
  'L',
  'W',
  'L',
  '15',
  'Bournemouth',
  '38 11 6 21 37 71 -34 39',
  'W',
  'L',
  'L',
  'L',
  'L',
  '16',
  'Nottingham Forest',
  '38 9 11 18 38 68 -30 38',
  'L',
  'W',
  'D',
  'W',
  'D',
  '17',
  'Everton',
  '38 8 12 18 34 57 -23 36',
  'D',
  'W',
  'L',
  'D',
  'W',
  '18',
  'Leicester City',
  '38 9 7 22 51 68 -17 34',
  'D',
  'L',
  'L',
  'D',
  'W',
  '19',
  'Leeds United',
  '38 7 10 21 48 78 -30 31',
  'L',
  'L',
  'D',
  'L',
  'L',
  '20',
  'Southampton',
  '38 6 7 25 36 73 -37 25',
  'L',
  'L',
  'L',
  'L',
  'D'],
 ['1',
  'Manchester City',
  '38 29 6 3 99 26 73 93',
  'W',
  'W',
  'W',
  'D',
  'W',
  '2',
  'Liverpool',
  '38 28 8 2 94 26 68 92',
  'W',
  'D',
  'W',
  'W',
  'W',
  '3',
  'Chelsea',
  '38 21 11 6 76 33 43 74',
  'L',
  'D',
  'W',
  'D',
  'W',
  '4',
  'Tottenham Hotspur',
  '38 22 5 11 69 40 29 71',
  'W',
  'D',
  'W',
  'W',
  'W',
  '5',
  'Arsenal',
  '38 22 3 13 61 48 13 69',
  'W',
  'W',
  'L',
  'L',
  'W',
  '6',
  'Manchester United',
  '38 16 10 12 57 57 0 58',
  'L',
  'D',
  'W',
  'L',
  'L',
  '7',
  'West Ham United',
  '38 16 8 14 60 51 9 56',
  'L',
  'L',
  'W',
  'D',
  'L',
  '8',
  'Leicester City',
  '38 14 10 14 62 59 3 52',
  'L',
  'W',
  'W',
  'D',
  'W',
  '9',
  'Brighton And Hove Albion',
  '38 12 15 11 42 44 -2 51',
  'D',
  'W',
  'W',
  'D',
  'W',
  '10',
  'Wolverhampton Wanderers',
  '38 15 6 17 38 43 -5 51',
  'L',
  'D',
  'L',
  'D',
  'L',
  '11',
  'Newcastle United',
  '38 13 10 15 44 62 -18 49',
  'W',
  'L',
  'L',
  'W',
  'W',
  '12',
  'Crystal Palace',
  '38 11 15 12 50 46 4 48',
  'W',
  'W',
  'D',
  'L',
  'W',
  '13',
  'Brentford',
  '38 13 7 18 48 56 -8 46',
  'D',
  'L',
  'W',
  'W',
  'L',
  '14',
  'Aston Villa',
  '38 13 6 19 52 54 -2 45',
  'W',
  'L',
  'D',
  'D',
  'L',
  '15',
  'Southampton',
  '38 9 13 16 43 67 -24 40',
  'D',
  'L',
  'L',
  'L',
  'L',
  '16',
  'Everton',
  '38 11 6 21 43 66 -23 39',
  'W',
  'D',
  'L',
  'W',
  'L',
  '17',
  'Leeds United',
  '38 9 11 18 42 79 -37 38',
  'L',
  'L',
  'L',
  'D',
  'W',
  '18',
  'Burnley',
  '38 7 14 17 34 53 -19 35',
  'W',
  'L',
  'L',
  'D',
  'L',
  '19',
  'Watford',
  '38 6 5 27 34 77 -43 23',
  'L',
  'L',
  'D',
  'L',
  'L',
  '20',
  'Norwich City',
  '38 5 7 26 23 84 -61 22',
  'L',
  'L',
  'L',
  'D',
  'L']]

I stored this in a Dataframe, however the output of that DataFrame looks likes this here. It is storing each season as 1 row instead of going down vertically, thats why it has 3 rows, and 160 columns. Ideally I want it to look just like the EPL Table like this ideal table.
I have tried transposing but it does not work, I'm guessing that I need to map the rows and columns myself, but I am quite new to pandas and hope someone can help.

maybe you should format it when you were scraping data. Maybe you should scrape row by row instead of scraping all at once. It could be simpler.

if you know how many elements is in row then you could slice it data[1:10] , data[10:19], etc  to get every row - you could run for-loopwithdata[i:i+9]. OR if you keep it in numpy.arraythen you canreshape` it.

if you have only problem with string '32 18 6 8 65 49 16 60' then could use .str.split(' ') to convert to list (in one cell) and later use explode to put every value in separated column

shorty: you have two different problems in data - and you should use different code for every problem. You can't do it in one command.

If you can't shape it upfront (when scraping), here is one way of some post-processing :
from itertools import chain, batched # >=3.12

df = (
    pd.DataFrame(batched(chain.from_iterable(table_data), 8))
    # @ouroboros1's variant
    # pd.DataFrame(np.array(table_data).reshape(-1, int(20*8/20)))
    .pipe(
        lambda raw: pd.concat(
            [
                raw.iloc[:, :2],                           # club's pos
                raw[2].str.split(expand=True).astype(int), # game details
                raw.iloc[:, 3:].agg(" ".join, axis=1),     # form
            ],
            axis=1,
        )
    )
    .set_axis(
        [
            "Position", "Club", "Played",
            "Won", "Draw", "Lost", "GF", "GA", "GD",
            "Points", "Form",
        ],
        axis=1,
    )
)

NB: You may want to add an identifier (here: 1, 2 and 3) to distinguish ranking times.
Output :
   Position             Club  Played  Won  Draw  Lost  GF  GA  GD  Points       Form
0         1          Arsenal      33   23     5     5  77  26  51      74  D W W L W
1         2        Liverpool      33   22     8     3  75  32  43      74  W W D L W
2         3  Manchester City      32   22     7     3  76  32  44      73  D D W W W
3         4      Aston Villa      34   20     6     8  71  50  21      66  W L D W W
..      ...              ...     ...  ...   ...   ...  ..  ..  ..     ...        ...
56       17     Leeds United      38    9    11    18  42  79 -37      38  L L L D W
57       18          Burnley      38    7    14    17  34  53 -19      35  W L L D L
58       19          Watford      38    6     5    27  34  77 -43      23  L L D L L
59       20     Norwich City      38    5     7    26  23  84 -61      22  L L L D L

[60 rows x 11 columns]


Nice solution. No need for itertools though. 20 teams per season * 8 values: pd.DataFrame(np.array(data).reshape(-1, int(20*8/20))). raw.iloc[:, 3:] should be raw.iloc[:, 2:], and split(expand=True).astype(int) seems nice.

Thanks @ouroboros1! Nice numpy's variant. Many roads leed to Rome ;)

Indeed they do ;). raw.iloc[:, 3:] should be raw.iloc[:, 2:] is nonsense; I got confused though, since 'Form' in your output is showing 4 results instead of 5: e.g. W W L W -> D W W L W. Well, OP will get the picture. S/he probably does well to review the scraping anyway. Fun exercise nonetheless.

Frankly, I think you should change code which you used for scraping and format it during scraping.
Maybe you should use more complex rules to scrape table by table and row by row instead of scraping all at once.

Now you have two different problems.

many rows in one row
values as single string in single row
and you should resolve every problem separatelly using different code. You can't do this in one command.


First doesn't need pandas.DataFrame but you can split every row to many rows using for-loop with slice row[i:i+8]
data  = [[ ... your data ... ]]

new_data = []

for row in data:
    for i in range(0, len(row), 8):
        part = row[i:i+8]
        new_data.apped(part)
        print(part)

Result:
['1', 'Arsenal', '33 23 5 5 77 26 51 74', 'D', 'W', 'W', 'L', 'W']
['2', 'Liverpool', '33 22 8 3 75 32 43 74', 'W', 'W', 'D', 'L', 'W']
['3', 'Manchester City', '32 22 7 3 76 32 44 73', 'D', 'D', 'W', 'W', 'W']
['4', 'Aston Villa', '34 20 6 8 71 50 21 66', 'W', 'L', 'D', 'W', 'W']
['5', 'Tottenham Hotspur', '32 18 6 8 65 49 16 60', 'L', 'W', 'D', 'W', 'L']
['6', 'Newcastle United', '32 15 5 12 69 52 17 50', 'L', 'W', 'D', 'W', 'W']
['7', 'Manchester United', '32 15 5 12 47 48 -1 50', 'W', 'D', 'L', 'D', 'D']
['8', 'West Ham United', '34 13 9 12 54 63 -9 48', 'L', 'D', 'W', 'L', 'L']
['9', 'Chelsea', '31 13 8 10 61 52 9 47', 'W', 'D', 'W', 'D', 'W']
['10', 'Brighton And Hove Albion', '32 11 11 10 52 50 2 44', 'W', 'L', 'D', 'L', 'D']
['11', 'Wolverhampton Wanderers', '33 12 7 14 46 53 -7 43', 'L', 'D', 'L', 'D', 'L']
['12', 'Fulham', '34 12 6 16 50 54 -4 42', 'D', 'L', 'L', 'W', 'L']
['13', 'Bournemouth', '33 11 9 13 48 60 -12 42', 'W', 'W', 'L', 'D', 'L']
['14', 'Crystal Palace', '33 9 9 15 42 56 -14 36', 'D', 'L', 'L', 'W', 'W']
['15', 'Brentford', '34 9 8 17 52 59 -7 35', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'W', 'W']
['16', 'Everton', '33 10 8 15 34 48 -14 30', 'L', 'D', 'W', 'L', 'W']
['17', 'Nottingham Forest', '34 7 9 18 42 60 -18 26', 'D', 'W', 'L', 'D', 'L']
['18', 'Luton Town', '34 6 7 21 47 75 -28 25', 'L', 'L', 'W', 'L', 'L']
['19', 'Burnley', '34 5 8 21 37 69 -32 23', 'D', 'D', 'L', 'D', 'W']
['20', 'Sheffield United', '33 3 7 23 31 88 -57 16', 'D', 'L', 'D', 'L', 'L']
['1', 'Manchester City', '38 28 5 5 94 33 61 89', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'D', 'L']
['2', 'Arsenal', '38 26 6 6 88 43 45 84', 'W', 'W', 'L', 'L', 'W']
['3', 'Manchester United', '38 23 6 9 58 43 15 75', 'L', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W']
['4', 'Newcastle United', '38 19 14 5 68 33 35 71', 'L', 'D', 'W', 'D', 'D']
['5', 'Liverpool', '38 19 10 9 75 47 28 67', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'D', 'D']
['6', 'Brighton And Hove Albion', '38 18 8 12 72 53 19 62', 'W', 'L', 'W', 'D', 'L']
['7', 'Aston Villa', '38 18 7 13 51 46 5 61', 'L', 'L', 'W', 'D', 'W']
['8', 'Tottenham Hotspur', '38 18 6 14 70 63 7 60', 'L', 'W', 'L', 'L', 'W']
['9', 'Brentford', '38 15 14 9 58 46 12 59', 'W', 'L', 'W', 'W', 'W']
['10', 'Fulham', '38 15 7 16 55 53 2 52', 'L', 'W', 'W', 'D', 'L']
['11', 'Crystal Palace', '38 11 12 15 40 49 -9 45', 'W', 'L', 'W', 'D', 'D']
['12', 'Chelsea', '38 11 11 16 38 47 -9 44', 'W', 'D', 'L', 'L', 'D']
['13', 'Wolverhampton Wanderers', '38 11 8 19 31 58 -27 41', 'L', 'W', 'L', 'D', 'L']
['14', 'West Ham United', '38 11 7 20 42 55 -13 40', 'L', 'W', 'L', 'W', 'L']
['15', 'Bournemouth', '38 11 6 21 37 71 -34 39', 'W', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L']
['16', 'Nottingham Forest', '38 9 11 18 38 68 -30 38', 'L', 'W', 'D', 'W', 'D']
['17', 'Everton', '38 8 12 18 34 57 -23 36', 'D', 'W', 'L', 'D', 'W']
['18', 'Leicester City', '38 9 7 22 51 68 -17 34', 'D', 'L', 'L', 'D', 'W']
['19', 'Leeds United', '38 7 10 21 48 78 -30 31', 'L', 'L', 'D', 'L', 'L']
['20', 'Southampton', '38 6 7 25 36 73 -37 25', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'D']
['1', 'Manchester City', '38 29 6 3 99 26 73 93', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'D', 'W']
['2', 'Liverpool', '38 28 8 2 94 26 68 92', 'W', 'D', 'W', 'W', 'W']
['3', 'Chelsea', '38 21 11 6 76 33 43 74', 'L', 'D', 'W', 'D', 'W']
['4', 'Tottenham Hotspur', '38 22 5 11 69 40 29 71', 'W', 'D', 'W', 'W', 'W']
['5', 'Arsenal', '38 22 3 13 61 48 13 69', 'W', 'W', 'L', 'L', 'W']
['6', 'Manchester United', '38 16 10 12 57 57 0 58', 'L', 'D', 'W', 'L', 'L']
['7', 'West Ham United', '38 16 8 14 60 51 9 56', 'L', 'L', 'W', 'D', 'L']
['8', 'Leicester City', '38 14 10 14 62 59 3 52', 'L', 'W', 'W', 'D', 'W']
['9', 'Brighton And Hove Albion', '38 12 15 11 42 44 -2 51', 'D', 'W', 'W', 'D', 'W']
['10', 'Wolverhampton Wanderers', '38 15 6 17 38 43 -5 51', 'L', 'D', 'L', 'D', 'L']
['11', 'Newcastle United', '38 13 10 15 44 62 -18 49', 'W', 'L', 'L', 'W', 'W']
['12', 'Crystal Palace', '38 11 15 12 50 46 4 48', 'W', 'W', 'D', 'L', 'W']
['13', 'Brentford', '38 13 7 18 48 56 -8 46', 'D', 'L', 'W', 'W', 'L']
['14', 'Aston Villa', '38 13 6 19 52 54 -2 45', 'W', 'L', 'D', 'D', 'L']
['15', 'Southampton', '38 9 13 16 43 67 -24 40', 'D', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L']
['16', 'Everton', '38 11 6 21 43 66 -23 39', 'W', 'D', 'L', 'W', 'L']
['17', 'Leeds United', '38 9 11 18 42 79 -37 38', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'D', 'W']
['18', 'Burnley', '38 7 14 17 34 53 -19 35', 'W', 'L', 'L', 'D', 'L']
['19', 'Watford', '38 6 5 27 34 77 -43 23', 'L', 'L', 'D', 'L', 'L']
['20', 'Norwich City', '38 5 7 26 23 84 -61 22', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'D', 'L']

Second problem may need to use pandas.DataFrame
It can use .str.split(' ') to convert string to list.
Later it can convert it to new DataFrame with values in separated columns and join it to original DataFrame
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
#print(df1)

# convert string to list
df1.iloc[:,2] = df1.iloc[:,2].str.split(' ')
#print(df1)

# create new dataframe with values in separated columns
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.iloc[:,2].to_list(), columns=['Played', 'Won', 'Drawn', 'Lost', 'GF', 'GA', 'GD', 'Points'])
#print(df2)

# add new columns to old dataframe
df = df1.join(df2)

# remove old column with list
df.drop(columns=[2], inplace=True)

print(df)

Result:
    0                         1  3  4  5  6  7 Played Won Drawn Lost  GF  GA   GD Points
0    1                   Arsenal  D  W  W  L  W     33  23     5    5  77  26   51     74
1    2                 Liverpool  W  W  D  L  W     33  22     8    3  75  32   43     74
2    3           Manchester City  D  D  W  W  W     32  22     7    3  76  32   44     73
3    4               Aston Villa  W  L  D  W  W     34  20     6    8  71  50   21     66
4    5         Tottenham Hotspur  L  W  D  W  L     32  18     6    8  65  49   16     60
5    6          Newcastle United  L  W  D  W  W     32  15     5   12  69  52   17     50
6    7         Manchester United  W  D  L  D  D     32  15     5   12  47  48   -1     50
7    8           West Ham United  L  D  W  L  L     34  13     9   12  54  63   -9     48
8    9                   Chelsea  W  D  W  D  W     31  13     8   10  61  52    9     47
9   10  Brighton And Hove Albion  W  L  D  L  D     32  11    11   10  52  50    2     44
10  11   Wolverhampton Wanderers  L  D  L  D  L     33  12     7   14  46  53   -7     43
11  12                    Fulham  D  L  L  W  L     34  12     6   16  50  54   -4     42
12  13               Bournemouth  W  W  L  D  L     33  11     9   13  48  60  -12     42
13  14            Crystal Palace  D  L  L  W  W     33   9     9   15  42  56  -14     36
14  15                 Brentford  D  D  D  W  W     34   9     8   17  52  59   -7     35
15  16                   Everton  L  D  W  L  W     33  10     8   15  34  48  -14     30
16  17         Nottingham Forest  D  W  L  D  L     34   7     9   18  42  60  -18     26
17  18                Luton Town  L  L  W  L  L     34   6     7   21  47  75  -28     25
18  19                   Burnley  D  D  L  D  W     34   5     8   21  37  69  -32     23
19  20          Sheffield United  D  L  D  L  L     33   3     7   23  31  88  -57     16
20   1           Manchester City  W  W  W  D  L     38  28     5    5  94  33   61     89
21   2                   Arsenal  W  W  L  L  W     38  26     6    6  88  43   45     84
22   3         Manchester United  L  W  W  W  W     38  23     6    9  58  43   15     75
23   4          Newcastle United  L  D  W  D  D     38  19    14    5  68  33   35     71
24   5                 Liverpool  W  W  W  D  D     38  19    10    9  75  47   28     67
25   6  Brighton And Hove Albion  W  L  W  D  L     38  18     8   12  72  53   19     62
26   7               Aston Villa  L  L  W  D  W     38  18     7   13  51  46    5     61
27   8         Tottenham Hotspur  L  W  L  L  W     38  18     6   14  70  63    7     60
28   9                 Brentford  W  L  W  W  W     38  15    14    9  58  46   12     59
29  10                    Fulham  L  W  W  D  L     38  15     7   16  55  53    2     52
30  11            Crystal Palace  W  L  W  D  D     38  11    12   15  40  49   -9     45
31  12                   Chelsea  W  D  L  L  D     38  11    11   16  38  47   -9     44
32  13   Wolverhampton Wanderers  L  W  L  D  L     38  11     8   19  31  58  -27     41
33  14           West Ham United  L  W  L  W  L     38  11     7   20  42  55  -13     40
34  15               Bournemouth  W  L  L  L  L     38  11     6   21  37  71  -34     39
35  16         Nottingham Forest  L  W  D  W  D     38   9    11   18  38  68  -30     38
36  17                   Everton  D  W  L  D  W     38   8    12   18  34  57  -23     36
37  18            Leicester City  D  L  L  D  W     38   9     7   22  51  68  -17     34
38  19              Leeds United  L  L  D  L  L     38   7    10   21  48  78  -30     31
39  20               Southampton  L  L  L  L  D     38   6     7   25  36  73  -37     25
40   1           Manchester City  W  W  W  D  W     38  29     6    3  99  26   73     93
41   2                 Liverpool  W  D  W  W  W     38  28     8    2  94  26   68     92
42   3                   Chelsea  L  D  W  D  W     38  21    11    6  76  33   43     74
43   4         Tottenham Hotspur  W  D  W  W  W     38  22     5   11  69  40   29     71
44   5                   Arsenal  W  W  L  L  W     38  22     3   13  61  48   13     69
45   6         Manchester United  L  D  W  L  L     38  16    10   12  57  57    0     58
46   7           West Ham United  L  L  W  D  L     38  16     8   14  60  51    9     56
47   8            Leicester City  L  W  W  D  W     38  14    10   14  62  59    3     52
48   9  Brighton And Hove Albion  D  W  W  D  W     38  12    15   11  42  44   -2     51
49  10   Wolverhampton Wanderers  L  D  L  D  L     38  15     6   17  38  43   -5     51
50  11          Newcastle United  W  L  L  W  W     38  13    10   15  44  62  -18     49
51  12            Crystal Palace  W  W  D  L  W     38  11    15   12  50  46    4     48
52  13                 Brentford  D  L  W  W  L     38  13     7   18  48  56   -8     46
53  14               Aston Villa  W  L  D  D  L     38  13     6   19  52  54   -2     45
54  15               Southampton  D  L  L  L  L     38   9    13   16  43  67  -24     40
55  16                   Everton  W  D  L  W  L     38  11     6   21  43  66  -23     39
56  17              Leeds United  L  L  L  D  W     38   9    11   18  42  79  -37     38
57  18                   Burnley  W  L  L  D  L     38   7    14   17  34  53  -19     35
58  19                   Watford  L  L  D  L  L     38   6     5   27  34  77  -43     23
59  20              Norwich City  L  L  L  D  L     38   5     7   26  23  84  -61     22


Now you can only rename columns and put them in different order.

You need to fix your input first. Notice that the stats from Played all the way to points are all in the same string. This isn't the prettiest code but it gets the job done
import pandas as pd


def fix_season(list_output):
    stats_counter = 0
    current_team = []
    fixed_output = []
    for idx in range(len(list_output)):
        element = list_output[idx]
        # fix formatting on stats
        if stats_counter==2:
            current_team.extend(element.split(" "))
            stats_counter += 1
        # Appends team to the final season table
        elif stats_counter == 8:
            fixed_output.append(current_team)
            stats_counter = 1
            current_team = [element]
        # Add Stat to current team
        else:
            current_team.append(element)
            stats_counter += 1
    return fixed_output

season1 = fix_season(output[0])

result = pd.DataFrame(season1)
print(result)

